# How can I prevent a (serialized) expression to unroll

Tags: powershell, expression, deserialization, unroll

Thanks to the PowerShell expression mode, PowerShell has some nice ways to de-serialize objects, like:

- the [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6) cmdlet
- the [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) cmdlet
- the call operator [`&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#call-operator-)
- [dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-6#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing) a PowerShell script file

My general expectation is that the result of an given expression should be the same as using one of above listed de-serialize commands on same serialized version of that expression (for background, see the [ConvertTo-Expression](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression/) answer on the ['Save hash table in PowerShell object notation (PSON)'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24854277/1701026) question).
In other words:

```
<Expression> <=> Invoke-Command {<Expression>} <=> &([ScriptBlock]::Create('<Expression>'))
<Expression> <=> Invoke-Expression '<Expression>'
```

Examples:

```
Get-ChildItem <=> &{Get-ChildItem}
Get-ChildItem <=> Invoke-Command {Get-ChildItem}
Get-ChildItem <=> Invoke-Expression 'Get-ChildItem'

1, 2, 3 <=> &{1, 2, 3}
1, 2, 3 <=> Invoke-Command {1, 2, 3}
1, 2, 3 <=> Invoke-Expression '1, 2, 3'
```

This indeed appears true for mainly every expression, but due to the fact that PowerShell unrolls (enumerates) the output by default, this definition deviates in the case an expression contain an array with a single item:

```
,1 <≠> Invoke-Command {,1}
,1 <≠> Invoke-Expression ',1'
,"Test" <≠> Invoke-Command {,"Test"}
,"Test" <≠> Invoke-Expression ',"Test"'
@("Test") <≠> Invoke-Command {@("Test")}
@("Test") <≠> Invoke-Expression '@("Test")'
,@("Test") <≠> Invoke-Command {,@("Test")}
,@("Test") <≠> Invoke-Expression ',@("Test")'
```

Is there a way to prevent that expressions get unrolled when the are invoked (de-serialized) in anyway?

<sub>I am considering to request for a `-NoEnumerate` parameter (similar to the  [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-6) cmdlet) for the `Invoke-Expression` on the [PowerShell GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues), but that will still leave the issue/question for the call operator and dot sourcing that do not support parameters...</sub>

Comment: I know powershell flattens expressions in some cases.  I don't think serializing is the right word.  That's for returning objects from a remote computer.  A serialized object wouldn't have methods.

Comment: The only way I can find:  `$a = @(&{,1})`

Comment: @js2010, with regards to ["serialization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170686/what-is-a-serialized-object-in-programming), all three commands listed commands: the `Invoke-Expression`, the call operator  (`&([ScriptBlock]::Create('<Expression>'))`) and dot sourcing are accepting plain text as input describing an object (which might -or not- come from a remote computer)...

Comment: @js2010, which regards to `$a = @(&{,1})`, this works for (single valued) arrays, but breaks the original definition for anything that is not an array (such as` valuedtypes` and `hashtables`) as e.g. `'Test' <≠> @(&{'Test'})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to prevent the default unrolling of (serialized) expressions:
**Wrap the expression in a HashTable**:

```
<Expression> <=> (Invoke-Command {@{e=<Expression>}})['e']
<Expression> <=> (Invoke-Expression '@{e=<Expression>}')['e']
```

**Examples:**

```
Get-ChildItem <=> (Invoke-Command {@{e=Get-ChildItem}})['e']
Get-ChildItem <=> (Invoke-Expression '@{e=Get-ChildItem}')['e']

1, 2, 3 <=> (Invoke-Command {@{e=1, 2, 3}})['e']
1, 2, 3 <=> (Invoke-Expression '@{e=1, 2, 3}')['e']

,1 <=> (Invoke-Command {@{e=,1}})['e']
,1 <=> (Invoke-Expression '@{e=,1}')['e']
```

I have further implemented this in a [ConvertFrom-Expression](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=convertfrom-expression) cmdlet, which the 
 following features:

- `-NoEnumerate` switch to prevent arrays with a single item to unroll
- `-NoNewScope` switch similar to `Invoke-Command`
- *Multiple* ScriptBlock *and/or* String items via the pipeline or the `-Expression` argument

**`ConvertFrom-Expression` Examples:**

```
PS C:>'2*3', {3*4}, '"Test"' | ConvertFrom-Expression
6
12
Test
```

```
PS C:> (ConvertFrom-Expression ',"Test"' -NoEnumerate) -Is [Array]
True
```